# How to find object properties with the same values among javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I would like to find values that are the same among javascript objects (perhaps later also add in a min , max statistic)
I got stuck right at the start as my code returns some unexpected output
(PS I am not looking for common properties, but for common properties that have the same values)

```js
var obj1 = { "oranges": 5, "apples": 3, "peaches": 1 };
var obj2 = { "oranges": 4, "apples": 3, "peaches": 0 };
var obj3 = { "oranges": 5, "apples": 3, "peaches": 5 };
var obj_common = {};

for (var property in obj1) {
  if (obj1[property] = obj2[property])
    obj_common[property] = obj1[property];
}

console.log(obj_common);
```

Comment: Single "=" is assigning values to variables, == and === are logical (comparison) operators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find common properties between JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199349/how-to-find-common-properties-between-javascript-objects)

Comment: Thx, I saw that question, but I am not looking for common properties, but for common properties with the same values :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` for a comparison.

**Explanation what your code does:**
The line `(obj1[property] = obj2[property])` assigns the value of `obj2[property]` to `obj1[property]`. Because an assignment expression in javascript returns the assigned value, the expression evaluates to `true` for `"oranges"` and `"apples"` (because `4` and `3` are truthy values) and `false` for `"peaches"` (because `0` is a falsy value).

Answer (score 0):

Please change = to == inside the if statement

- = will assign value in right hand side to the variable in left hand side
- == will compare value in both sides (eg 1=='1' gives true)
- === use triple = if you want check both value and its type(1==='1' gives false)

```js
var obj1 = { "oranges": 5, "apples": 3, "peaches": 1 };
var obj2 = { "oranges": 4, "apples": 3, "peaches": 0 };
var obj3 = { "oranges": 5, "apples": 3, "peaches": 5 };
var obj_common = {};

for (var property in obj1) {
  if (obj1[property] == obj2[property])
    obj_common[property] = obj1[property];
}

console.log(obj_common);
```